# Delete record from database using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP file which displays data from a database. I'm using `while()` to display each of the records.

My PHP file:

```
<?php

    $flightTicketsSQL = "SELECT * FROM `flightbookings` WHERE username='$user' AND cancelled='no'";
    $flightTicketsQuery = $conn->query($flightTicketsSQL);

    while($flightTicketsRow = $flightTicketsQuery->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="tableElementTags text-center"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["bookingID"]; ?></td>
        <td class="tableElementTags text-center"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["origin"]; ?></td>
        <td class="tableElementTags text-center"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["destination"]; ?></td>
        <td class="tableElementTags text-center"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["date"]; ?></td>
        <td class="tableElementTags text-center"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["mode"]; ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="fa fa-remove tableElementTags pullSpan" id="deleteAccount"></span></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

If the user clicks on the last `<td>` (the one with the Font Awesome icon), I want the record with the particular bookingID be deleted from the database.

To do this I'll need to identify the value using jQuery `.val()`

My JS file:

```
var id = $("**WHAT DO I PUT HERE ?**").val();

    $('#deleteAccount').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'cancelTicket.php',
            data: { bookingID : id },
            success : function() {
                alert("Cancelled");
            }
        });
    });
```

My cancel.php file:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "database";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $user = $_SESSION["username"];
    $id = $_POST["bookingID"];


    $cancelFlightBookingsSQL = "UPDATE `flightbookings` SET cancelled='yes' WHERE bookingID='$id'";
    $cancelFlightBookingsQuery = $conn->query($cancelFlightBookingsSQL);
```

My question is how do I make jQuery identify which booking the user wants to be cancelled? I mean how do I assign an id to the `<td>` so that I can retrieve its value in the JS.

**I know I could not frame this question properly.  SORRY ABOUT THAT.**

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `id="deleteAccount"` element that's actually being clicked?

Comment: 1. You have no `#deleteAccount` element. 2. Make sure that you're not duplicating that `id` on each row. 3. Get the `id` from the button *within* the click handler using the `this` reference to get the clicked element

Comment: @David It'll be in the `<span class="fa fa-remove tableElementTags pullSpan"></span>`. I've not added it. I'll edit the question and add it.

Comment: Which `td` holds the value which should be sent in the request?

Comment: *("**WHAT DO I PUT HERE ?**")* That would be the `id` value of the `DOM` element, which currently is none. You could pass the id in the `id` param as `<td class="text-center" id="<?=$flightTicketsRow['id'];?>">`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The first one. $flightTicketsRow["bookingID"] should be the value to be sent.

Comment: Or better yet, create a function which activates on click and you can pass the `id` as a function `param`. For e.g. `onclick="cancelFlight(<?=$flightTicketsRow['id'];?>);"`

Comment: @Samuel Could you please explain a bit ? Thanks.

Comment: When you generate the page, insert your bookingIds as HTML IDs in the page and then use those

Comment: @Samuel don't do that. `on*` attributes are an anti pattern which should be avoided. Use an unobtrusive event handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan agreed. that makes good sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly you need to use a `class` for the `span` instead of an `id`, otherwise it will be duplicated in the DOM by your PHP loop,  which will result in invalid HMTL that will break your click event handler.

Once you've done that you need to set the `id` variable value *within* the click handler so that you can find the `td` related to the clicked element. You can do that like this:

```html
<!-- repeated throughout your while loop -->
<td class="text-center">
  <span class="fa fa-remove tableElementTags pullSpan deleteAccount"></span>
</td>
```

```js
$('.deleteAccount').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text().trim();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'cancelTicket.php',
    data: {
      bookingID: id
    },
    success: function() {
      alert("Cancelled");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Can you give any more information, as that's not really enough to debug. Are there any errors in the console? Are you running the jQuery code in a document.ready event handler?

Comment: No errors. Nothing. The code just doesn't run. The data is not updated in the DB.

Comment: If you check the network tab of the console can you see the request being made? If so, what's the response text and status code?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb, but where's the network tab? I'm very very new to these things.

Comment: Assuming you're using Chrome then it's in the tabs at the top of the Console. Other browsers may look slightly different, but it should be available in there too, somewhere.

Comment: Okay let me find it.

Comment: Nope. No request's being made.

Comment: In which case you're not hooking up the event correctly. Are you sure you've put the jQuery in a document.ready event handler? Also, if the rows are being added dynamically - say as the result of a AJAX request - you'll need to use a delegated event handler, so try replacing `$('.deleteAccount').click(function() {` with `$(document).on('click', '.deleteAccount', function() {`

Comment: Wait wait wait. The code you provided is working in Chrome. In Chrome an alert pops out saying (Cancelled). But in Firefox it doesn't.

Comment: The record is updated in the DB too if I use Chrome. But why doesn't it work in Firefox?

Comment: jQuery is entirely cross browser, and there's nothing out of the ordinary here which would cause any inconsistency. I'd check that you're not looking at a cached version of the page in Firefox.

Comment: Okay. I'm checking.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me out. I've got to learn many new things from you. I really didn't know about that request monitor kinda thing. I know I'm nowhere near to you in coding. But in case you need any help ever, you can reach me out. Thank You again.

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you to offer. The console is great :) I'd really suggest you spend some time figuring out how it works as it's invaluable when debugging any HTML/CSS/JS problems.

Comment: Sure. I will :)

Answer (score 2):

From the clicked element:

```
$('#deleteAccount').click(function() {
```

You can navigate the DOM to find the element you want.  First, add a class to that target element:

```
<td class="tableElementTags text-center bookingID"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["bookingID"]; ?></td>
```

Next, also put that Booking ID value in a data attribute for easy programmatic access (personal preference, since things like text content can easily change):

```
<td class="tableElementTags text-center bookingID" data-booking="<?php echo $flightTicketsRow["bookingID"]; ?>"><?php echo $flightTicketsRow["bookingID"]; ?></td>
```

Now from within the click handler you can navigate up the DOM to the closest common parent element and then back down to the target element with the data you want.  Something like this:

```
$('#deleteAccount').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.bookingID').data('booking');
    // the rest of your click handler
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and let you know.